# Redirecting using 301 rule in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am having a problem with redirecting a page from example.com (to) www.example.com

The code I have is:

```
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.subdomain.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

And it is not working, any help?

Comment: Does my answer help? Do you need something additional?

Comment: How is it "not working"? Does it not redirect? Do you get a 500 error?

Comment: It does not redirect and it gives me the openDNS page

Comment: Do you have configured your ServerAlias to handle www.subdomain.com ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is force the www version of your domain?  Just do this...

```
# Force www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That will certainly work for example.com to www.example.com, which is what your question specified, unless you don't have mod_rewrite installed or your Apache config files are not allowing your .htaccess to work. If you have specific subdomain needs, perhaps you should repost with your exact situation.

Comment: I use this all the time (hundreds of websites, literally) and it works fine. Yours is slightly different because its a subdomain but should work just as well, if it's not, I would check with your host provider and make sure they don't have any restrictions

Answer (score 0):

This is what my rewrite looks like, and it works:

```
## REWRITE RULES
# enable rewrite
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# enforce a specific domain in the url
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sub.domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

This rule will redirect anything that is NOT `www.sub.domain.com` to `www.sub.domain.com`.

Comment: The thing is I am redirecting subdomain.blah.com (to) www.subdomain.blah.com so I need the www (and your solution above did not work unfortunately :( )

Comment: I have updated my answer. Notice the exclamation point in my condition.  The condition I use doesn't have the `sub` portion.

Answer (score 0):

Update: based on your comment `It does not redirect and it gives me the openDNS page`, I believe your problem is not (yet?) with mod_rewrite.

Try adding `Options +FollowSymlinks` before `RewriteEngine On`, then add `RewriteBase /` after `RewriteEngine On`.

I recommend reading sections `Fatal Redirection` and `rewrite logging` found [here](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php).

You can enable `mod_rewrite` debugging to see what is going on (if anything!):

```
RewriteLog "/tmp/rewrite.log"`
RewriteLogLevel 5
```